# How to unhide the /Users folder while in Recovery Mode in OSX

Tags: macos, terminal, recovery

I'm trying to access some files in my home directory on my macbook, using the terminal on recovery mode. In a normal boot, I can do:

```
sudo chflags nohidden /Users
```

to unhide the Users folder, but this is not working on recovery mode. I've tried [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/236210/no-macintosh-hd-in-volumes-folder):

```
diskutil list
```

but no encrypted and/or offline Volumes appear. Does someone know how can I access my files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, so I just needed to mount the partition from Disk Utility, using File->Mount with the correct partition selected. After that, I can access my data.